# HP UX: how to use -or -and operators in find() function

Tags: find, hp-ux

I'm trying to to get a list of files with find() on HP UX

```
LD_PRELOAD = "`find ./lib/ -type f \( -name \*boo\* -or -name \*foo\* -and -not -name \*zoo\* \)`"
```

and HP UX console tells me that -or / -and / -not operators are bad.

meanwhile this stuff is working normal on linux redhat...

what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try omitting the minus signs and write them in all caps maybe?

-name *boo* OR -name *foo* AND NOT -name *zoo*

Or, alternatively, install GNU find so your script will work on both platforms without modification.

Comment: Thank you bro, that was helpfult suggestion. The fact of a matter is that i dont have admin rights to install new features on the company's server

Comment: Well, did removing the dash and uppercasing the booleans work at least? The hpux find man page seems to think so...

Comment: Yes, mate, thank you very much indeed :) This worked perfectly :) BTW I've read man pages for find() on that server and there were no any words about uppercase operators. This could be caused by my inattention, bro. But thank you :)